# Why my .php cant find a bitmap using a .js path?

Tags: javascript, php, path

I have the next web site folder structure (in short):

- Root_folder

  - PHP_folder

    - index.php
  - Javascript_folder

    - app.js
  - Assets_folder

    - my_texture.jpg

..."index.php" calls "app.js" with the line:

```
<?php include '../Javascript_folder/app.js'; ?>
```

...and "app.js" calls "my_texture.jpg" with the line:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../Assets_folder/my_texture.jpg");
```

... but "my_texture.jpg" is not found.

If I put "my_texture.jpg" in the same folder of "index.php" and change the javascript path to:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./my_texture.jpg");
```

... the bitmap is found, but obviously I prefer to keep the assets in their own folder.

How could I find the bitmap respecting my current folder structure?

Comment: What URL do you see for the JPG in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: GET http://localhost:4000/Assets_folder/my_texture.jpg (I am simplifying the folder and file names)

Comment: Maybe something in your `.htaccess` file is blocking external access to `Assets_folder`. Can you access other files there?

Comment: No, I cannot access the "Assets_folder" files. Just in case I am running my site inside my Ubuntu computer with a php server

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file to see what folders it allows access to.

Answer (score 0):

0K
I resolved this issue opening the Ubuntu terminal (bash/Ubuntu) **within the root folder** of my site:

```
Root_folder$ php -S localhost:4000/PHP_folder/index.php
```

My local server cant find the sub-folder "Assets_folder" files when I execute the server within the sub-folder "Assets_folder/PHP_folder/" with this order:

```
Root_folder/PHP_folder$ php -S localhost:4000/index.php
```

In short, **using bash terminal/php local server must be initied from the root folder of the site**.

Also, I want to warning that some remote servers (like the one that Im paying) doesn't have the .htaccess file.

I have to create and write the .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex PHP_folder/index.php
```

I am a Spanish speaking self-taught programmer and I hope I did not use incorrect terms